# Azure devops - 302 status code when publishing universal package

Tags: azure, azure-devops

i am trying to publish artifact from my local host to azure devops as universal package. I downloaded newest azure CLI (2.3.1) installed newest azure devops (0.18.0). After that i logged in using `az login` and also created my own personal access token and logged in with `az devops login` command. There were no errors so i assume that i logged in, i also did it with debug enabled and everything went fine.
After that i tried to publish my universal package into artifacts in my project but i got message

> Failed to update Universal Packages tooling. Operation returned a 302
>   status code.

[Error screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GjhUu.png)

In debug mode i've got

> failed while trying to get token for tenant {tenant_id}

Later on there was also a retry with PAT but again 302 status from OPTIONS request.
I also tried to do other actions on my account using cli and everything was ok. I removed user from my team and it went smoothly.
Can i ask for help with this issue, if there is other option to publish this package it would be great.

Comment: May I know what’s the status of this? Does below methods are help to you? Free to comment if you still has any question to it:-)

Answer (score 0):

The operation of `Package publish` from **Azure cli** need the support of `artifacttool`, so we combine these 2 operation together. When you run the command of `az artifacts universal publish`, it will firstly **install**/**update** the `artifact tool` to latest, so that it could make sure the `publish` action can be smoothly.

Now, the issue you faced is during the `artifact tool` updating. Not sure what happened on your side since it all work fine for me at present. I did universal package publish very successfully just now.

---

**Work around:**

Since you stuck at `artifact tool` updating, just avoid that. You can do package publish by using Azure devops task.

Just go **pipeline**, add `Universal packages` task and then configure it with below arguments:

[image]

Then, run this pipeline with [**self-agent**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/agents?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser#install)(must). Because your are trying to publish the local files to Azure Universal package, only self-host agent can have ability to access local folder.